# RSA Key work only with my user

Tags: ssh, openssl

My ssh key work normally, i can connect directly to other server with:

> MyUser@host1:    ssh server

No passphrase is requested and the connection success , but when i use root:

> root@host1: ssh -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub MyUser@server

the other server request a passphrase, can anyone explain to me why the connection is not automatic as the first case and how resolve this issue ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the passphrase is cached by an `ssh-agent` for your user but not for root, then I don't think this is surprising.

Comment: Yeap i use putty agent, how can i add my keys to root user also ?

Comment: It's not the other server that asking for the passphrase, it's your client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're logging in to host1 as MyUser and then using either `su -` or `sudo` to switch to root. Both of those methods will remove most or all environment variables when making the transition from one user account to another, for security.

(For example, if you were only allowed to run specific commands as root with `sudo`, you could work around this restriction with an evil `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable setting if environment variables were all automatically passed along.)

When you're using a SSH authentication agent, then one important environment variable is created for your SSH session on host1: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. When you SSH onward to server as MyUser, the presence of this variable tells host1's SSH client that an authentication agent connection is available. The variable points to a Unix socket, typicallly located in a directory under /tmp that is only accessible by its owner. This socket is connected to the `sshd` process that handles your connection from your workstation to host1, and ultimately to the PuTTY authentication agent on your workstation.

If this variable is not passed along when `su`ing or `sudo`ing from one user account to another, the SSH client won't be able to use the authentication agent connection after the transition. As a result, it needs to prompt for a passphrase to decrypt any available private keys on its own.

Also, if you transition to another non-root account, the file permissions on the socket and the directory it's contained in will stop you from using it, unless you take steps to explicitly allow it before transitioning to the other user. (This is not an issue when transitioning to root, because root can access everything.)

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub MyUser@server
```

You're using the wrong key file here. **id_rsa.pub** contains the public key which is installed on the remote server. **id_rsa** (without the *.pub* extension) contains the private private key which clients use to authenticate to the remote server.

Specify the name of the private key instead of the public key:

```
ssh -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa MyUser@server
                         ^^^^^^--Note no .pub
```